# Configure webpack publicPath setting has no effect

Tags: node.js, meteor, reactjs, webpack

I have setup a dev server running, meteor, react, webpack.  When I load up the site located here: vps.elemental.co.za:3000 all starts off OK until it tries to load the webpack web.js.  It is trying to load this file from localhost:3500 which is obviously incorrect and cannot be found.

I have tried to configure the output.publicPath setting in my webpackconfig to point to vps.elemental.co.za:3000/assets/ but this setting doesn't seem to affect anything?

Perhaps my understanding of this settings purpose is incorrect, either way does anybody know how to fix this 'localhost' issue?
My webpack config is as follows:

```
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        'babel-polyfill',
        './entry'
    ],
    output:{
        publicPath: "http://vps.elemental.co.za:3000/assets"
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.json','css','scss']
    },
    devServer:{

    },
    devtool: 'eval',
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test:/\.html$/,
                loader:'html-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                    plugins:['transform-runtime'],
                    presets:['es2015','stage-0','react']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader:  'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader!postcss-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
                loaders: [
                    'url?limit=8192',
                    'img-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                loader: 'file?name=public/fonts/[name].[ext]'
            }
        ]
    },
    postcss: [ autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 2 versions'] }) ]
};
```

Comment: Are you positive that you're running webpack-dev-server on port 3000 with that hostname?

Comment: I'm afraid I wasn't aware I need to use webpack-dev-server to do this.  When I run it with commandline options for domain and port, it doesn't seem to do anything on its own.  Do I need to run it while meteor is running? Or how does this work?